# Как можно ограничить количество символов на ввод в блоке с contenteditable="true"?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Необходимо поставить ограничитель на 180 символов в блок:

```
<h1 class="name" id="name" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Заголовок"></h1>
```

Comment: [google - первая ссылка](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&ei=vYFKXbhTjrKbBeimjvAD&q=contenteditable+max+characters&oq=conteneditable+max+&gs_l=psy-ab.3.2.0i13l4j0i22i30l6.4396.4827..7714...0.0..1.303.603.2j1j0j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i22i10i30.2KA1N-BmHrI)

Comment: @Nilsan Воистину спасибо! :)

Comment: Пожалуйста, пользуйтесь почаще гуглом, как показывает опыт 99% вопросов уже решено, если что-то не решено то по частям можно собрать самостоятельно решение. Это хоть и дольше, но это плюс в копилку знаний.